# how to scale images the correct way?

Tags: html, css, image

So I have a row of images which is part of a responsive layout. the container goes form edge to edge. The only problematic area seems to be these images are distorting when the screen is expanded and scaled down again. Is there a real solution t handle this. I must add that images are to be loaded in with php so I don;t think I have an option for sing background images? That would be ideal of course.

I am trying to retain the scale of the images without them distorting in either height or width but I can not seem to achieve this?

[Demo of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/iamdanbarrett/kdyjtq9x/)

```
/******* gallery *******/

.gallery{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #D2D7D3;
    height: auto;
    overflow:auto;
}

.gallery img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.gallery_col1{
    width: 20%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #BFBFBF;
    float: left;
}

.gallery_col2{
    width: 20%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #BFBFBF;
    float: left;
}

.gallery_col3{
    width: 20%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #BFBFBF;
    float: left;
}


.gallery_col4{
    width: 20%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #BFBFBF;
    float: left;
}

.gallery_col5{
    width: 20%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #BFBFBF;
    float: left;
}

.gallery_col6{
    display: none;
}

.gallery_col7{
    display: none;
}
```

```
    <div class="gallery_col1">

        <img src="http://paramwebeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/demo.png" />

    </div>

    <div class="gallery_col2">

        <img src="http://paramwebeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/demo.png" />

    </div> 

    <div class="gallery_col3">

        <img src="http://paramwebeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/demo.png" />

    </div>

    <div class="gallery_col4">

        <img src="http://paramwebeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/demo.png" />

    </div>

    <div class="gallery_col5">

        <img src="http://paramwebeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/demo.png" />

    </div> 

    <div class="gallery_col6">

        <img src="http://paramwebeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/demo.png" />

    </div>             

    <div class="gallery_col7">

        <img src="http://paramwebeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/demo.png" />

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

**1)** Keep your current HTML and add:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/kdyjtq9x/1/)

```
.gallery img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

---

**2)** Move the images from being `img` tags to being the background images of your `div`s, then use `background-size:contain;`, `background-repeat:no-repeat;` and backgorund-position:center center;`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/kdyjtq9x/2/)

```
.gallery div {
    background-image:url(http://paramwebeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/demo.png);
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: And that is doable if I am wanting to use php? So the images will be different from user to user.